# Preferred way to find a transaction's block

Tags: transactions, blocks

With the history plugin deprecated, what's the preferred way to find out which block a transaction is in?

Comment: There is mongo db plugin now, as replacement if history plugin

Comment: @damianodamiano If you add that as an answer instead of a comment I'll accept it.

Comment: done! also i've added a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [mongo_db_plugin](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/mongo_db_plugin) now, as replacement for history plugin